# How do I troubleshoot a blank page in phpFox?

Tags: sql

Has anyone ever had their site go blank?

I'm not sure what happened, everything has been running fine, until yesterday. Looks like the server is up, domain is okay, mysql server is okay too, but for some reason the site is blank.

The last thing i did was install vbulletin with a prefix. And that's about the time it messed up.

I tried to drop all the vbulletin tables, as well as any other tables that doesn't have to do with phpfox, but looks like site is still blank.

I tried to log in to the admincp via "http://mysite.com/admincp" and it goes to "http://mysite.com/index.php?do=/user/login/" but the page is still blank.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yeh sounds like there's a leak in your code mate. Double check everything to make sure you close brackets where you should and end html where you should.